# How do I make Google Analatycs events on button only fire once per user even with multiple clicks?

Tags: google, analytics, goals, analytics-events

I need to set up Google events and goals on the buttons of application form. Lets say, you need to write your name, e-mail, phone number and the press "Next" to reach the second form which you should fill too.

So you've pressed "Next" button after you wrote your name, e-mail, phone number but you made a mistake and need to correct your phone number. You did the corrections and the pressed the "Next" button once again.

So in total you've pressed that button two times and that means you did two goals. If you click 100 times the button, You'll generate 100 goals/events.

How can I set up it so your press of the "Next" button would calculate as only one goal and event and not 100 in Analytics report? I do not need hundreds of goals of a user who just clicked one button many times.

Comment: I could be wrong, by my understanding is that even if a user fires and event multiple times, you shouldn't see multiple goals that are associated with an event.

Answer (score 1):

Google analytics will only record one of that goal per session. In essence, it's reporting on the deduped 'Unique Events' figure, not the Total Events.

Comment: That is what I think too.   Do you point to the documentation where GA explains this?